# jQuery reset form values + invalid errors

Tags: jquery, reset

I've got this piece of code in my jquery validation script:

```
resetForm: function() {
        if ( $.fn.resetForm )
            $( this.currentForm ).resetForm();
        this.submitted = {};
        this.prepareForm();
        this.hideErrors();
        this.elements().removeClass( this.settings.errorClass );
    }
```

this is exactly what I need, thus I would like to use it. I've tried to bind it with an onclick, absent success. I just need a button/link that calls this function. Can you advice me on this?

Comment: Where is the function defined? It looks like its inside of an options object, which means it won't be accessible.

Comment: That's a default JQuery validate function (contained in jquery.validate.js). It should be callable on a validator object http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/resetForm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try this, it should work (assuming you have a button with an id myButton and a form called myForm):

```
$("#myButton").click(function () {
    var validator = $("#myform").validate();
    validator.resetForm();
});
```

Comment: Just a note: this does not work if the form is hidden (display: none).
So it's necessary to show it before using resetForm.